# Grails Twitter Bootstrap Plugin Issue with navbar-fixed-top

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, grails-plugin, gsp

I am using `Grails 2.1.0` and `Twitter Bootstrap Plugin 2.1.1` and am encountering an issue with `navbar-fixed-top`.

In order to get the Navbar fixed to the top of the page to behave correctly during resize, the [Twitter Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) states:

> Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the . Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS.

How can I do this when using the Grails Plugin for Twitter Bootstrap?

Here is what I have tried:

**main.gsp**

```
<head>
  ...
  <r:require modules="bootstrap-css"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 60px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav {
      padding: 9px 0;
    }
  </style>
  <r:require modules="bootstrap-responsive-css"/>
  <r:layoutResources/>
</head>
```

The problem is that Grails Plugin for Twitter Bootstrap takes the content of `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css` and combines them into the following merged file: `static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css`.

Thus, I am not able to put the body padding style "after core Bootstrap CSS and before Responsive CSS" as per Twitter Bootstrap docs.

**Here is the View Source HTML that I get from the main.gsp above**

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
  }
</style>

<link href="/homes/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" 
    rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
```

If there is no way to do this, I could always just drop the Grails Twitter Bootstrap Plugin and manually download Twitter Bootstrap and put it my Grails Project's `web-app/css`, `web-app/images`, and `web-app/js`.  However, I would like to be able to use the Grails Twitter Bootstrap Plugin.

Thank you very much in advance, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap recommends that place for the style because when the screen width goes below `980px` navbar becomes `static` (not `fixed`). So calling `bootstrap-responsive.css` after the `padding` prevents from a blank space at the top in mobile devices (there's not fxed element to fill that padding).

You can reproduce this behaviour using a media query:

```
@media (min-width:980px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

Put this CSS anywhere in your stylesheets, and don't worry about your `<links>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Just need to make sure I understand ... if I add an inline style block `<style type="text/css"> (your media query solution here) </style>`, it can be after the combined CSS file created by Grails Twitter Bootstrap Plugin  `<link href="/homes/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />`, I do not need to add it to the `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap-responsive.css`.  Is this correct?

Comment: You can add that rule as an `<style>` block or in your stylesheet file. Exactly, you don't have to change bootstrap files.

Comment: By the way, after getting your `padding`, try diferent screen/window sizes to check if responsiveness still works ;)